# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql-server-2008

While executing my query i got the error stated "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"   below is my query.

```
select OrderLog_Initiated, OrderLog_SessionDateTime 
into #FullMemberOrderLog
from tbl_orderlog   
where CONVERT(date,OrderLog_Initiated) between '2013-03-03' and '2013-03-08' -- order     by OrderLog_Initiated     

insert into #FullMemberOrderLog 
select OrderLog_Initiated, OrderLog_SessionDateTime 
from tbl_orderlog 
where CONVERT(date,OrderLog_Initiated) between '2013-03-03' and '2013-03-08'
select #result = (cast(DATEDIFF(HOUR,CONVERT(date,'OrderLog_Initiated'),CONVERT(date,'OrderLog_SessionDateTime' )) as float) ) from  #FullMemberOrderLog
```

Kindly some one help me in this issue, Really i'm frying... My Expected result is Compare the 'OrderLog_Initiated' table with the 'OrderLog_SessionDateTime' table and provide the time difference in Hours, But i cannot get what i expected. Kindly someone help me, Really thank you very much In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying:

```
CONVERT(date,'OrderLog_Initiated')
```

Try:

```
CONVERT(date,OrderLog_Initiated)
```

(No single quotes around column names, otherwise it is just treated as a string.)

Also, why are you performing both a `SELECT INTO` and an `INSERT INTO` with the exact same query? Pick one.

And finally, why are you saying:

```
SELECT #result =
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT result =
```

?

Comment: Hi,   Thanks for your reply. I will do that , But i expect a result in Hours.  In OrderLog_Initiated and OrderLog_SessionDateTime table i stored date & time format in '2013-03-19 19:51:43.470'.  So how could i get my result in Hours.

Comment: Hi, Thank You very much for your suggestion, Now i got proper data, but while comparing the two tables (Orderlog_Iniated  and Orderlog_Sessiondatetime), i can get only the time defference in the multiplies of 24 only, but i need More accuracy in my result like 1 hour, 2,3,4 etc... Kindly help me Please..

Comment: @Keerthi show sample data and desired results *in your question* (not in a comment). I'm not very good at vague word problems, sorry.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying Mr.Aaron, Kindly refer my below query and output.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying Mr.Aaron, Kindly refer my below output.    select 

Output : 24 , 0 , 24 , 36 , 48.    I want to know how can i get my exact values in 1hour, 2 hour etc.

Comment: @Keerthi I just asked you to please not put sample data and desired results ***in a comment***. Plus how the heck is anybody supposed to know why the output should be 24, 0, 24, 36, 48? What is the input? We have no idea!

Comment: Hi, Sorry Here's my Query.....       select 
OrderLog_Initiated,
OrderLog_SessionDateTime 
into #FullMemberOrderLog
from tbl_orderlog   
where CONVERT(date,OrderLog_Initiated) between '2013-03-02' and '2013-03-03' -- order by OrderLog_Initiated  

insert into #FullMemberOrderLog 
 select 
OrderLog_Initiated, 
OrderLog_SessionDateTime from
tbl_orderlog 
where CONVERT(date,OrderLog_Initiated) between '2013-03-02' and '2013-03-03'
select #Result = (cast(DATEDIFF(HOUR,CONVERT(date,OrderLog_Initiated),CONVERT(date,OrderLog_SessionDateTime )) as float) ) from  #FullMemberOrderLog